# html child length returns 0 - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is part of my code:

```
range.setStart(range.startContainer.firstChild, index);
```

And here is what the firstChild looks like:

[image]

You can see that wholeText has some value, but when I do range.startContainer.firstChild.length gives me 0. Why is that?

Comment: What is firstChild supposed to be ? A text node ? A NodeList ?

Comment: @phtrivier A text node.

Comment: @petko_stankoski could you add some actual markup ? It's not clear where the phrase "100 gram !indisc" is, and since wholeText also contains the adjacent text, it can be confusing...

Answer (score 2):

Because `range.startContainer.firstChild` is object.

You should do `range.startContainer.firstChild.toString().length`.